# How to fetch selected image in the next page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have dropdown option to get image and on selecting option image shows up. I want to get same image in next page. How can I achieve that?

**index.php**

```
    <div class="col-md-2" style="color: #000; font-family:Titillium Web">
      <span style="color: #fff"> Pickup Location * </span>
      <select class='selectpicker1' id='colorselector' name='pickup_loc'>
        <option value=''></option>
        <option value='Building1'>Building1</option>
        <option value='Building2'>Building2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <br> <input type="text" id="pwr1" class="required p-control" name="pickup_ward" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2" style="color: #000; font-family:Titillium Web ">
      <span style="color: #fff">  Drop Location *</span>
      <select class='selectpicker2' id='dropselector' name='drop_loc'>
        <option value=''></option>
        <option value='Floor1'>Floor1</option>
        <option value='Floor2'>Floor2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="container colorselector show-image output">
      <div id="Building1" class="colors Building2">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWb3sciAdSaUG1Up0xz9facEB2bWr_OPZG6jNzHaQKcmwDBTB2iA" style="width: 100%" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>

      <div id="Building2" class="colors Building2">
        <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/MJguYcgKkDes6NzbE8Y0OgdyF64=/0x0:1500x974/1200x800/filters:focal(630x367:870x607)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56258041/2401_Third_Ave.0.jpg" style="width: 100%" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container dropselector show-image output">
      <div id="Floor1" class="colors Floor1">
        <img src="https://images.mydoorsign.com/img/lg/S/1-floor-number-braille-sign-se-6089.png" style="width: 100%" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>

      <div id="Floor2" class="colors Floor2">
        <img src="https://images.mydoorsign.com/img/lg/S/2-floor-number-braille-sign-se-6090.png" style="width: 100%" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>
    $('#colorselector, #dropselector').change(function() {
  var select = $(this);
  $('.' + select.attr("id") + ' .colors').hide();
  $('#' + select.val()).show();
});
```

I want to get the selected image in the next page.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can use **session storage** to achieve this.

On first page set the image URL with a desired unique key.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("myImage", "some url");
```

Then on the next page, retrieve the image:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("myImage");
```

Comment: I have no idea how to write it. Can you please help me and explain bit more on that.

Comment: @PraveenKumarL what are you confused about?
I have proposed two lines of code, put the first one inside your .change method and on the next page where you want to retrieve, use the second line and it would return the url that you had set previously. Its just like setting value to a variable and then accessing it via its name.

Comment: I am getting the url in next page. I don't want url to display i want the image to be displayed in the next page.

Comment: @PraveenKumarL That doesn't make sense, if you are able to get the selected URL on next page then what's the issue in setting it as a src of an <img/> tag?

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem("floor1", "<img src='images/flor1.jpg'>"); I have given it like this then also it is not showing image but showing only path.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to add the whole tag to your storage. Just do `sessionStorage.setItem("floor1", "images/flor1.jpg");`. Now on next page where you want to get this value do `sessionStorage.getItem("floor1")`;. On that page you can have an empty <img> tag with an id. Once you have the value, you can grab it and set its source as the value retrieved from session storage.